# Alert() twice in simple angular app

Tags: angularjs, alert

Alert function is firing off twice, I can't figure out why: http://jsfiddle.net/ntzLrkmz/2/

It's going to alert when a `!number` is inserted at `<input type="number">`

EDIT: thanks all, I'll be playing with this useful information

Comment: Digest cycle runs twice, alerts twice.

Comment: So no way to prevent this? just not using alert anymore?, could anyone further explain. Researching, but It'd be nice a short answer

Comment: Angular runs `$digest` cycles whenever content changes and needs to be binded back to the view. Each time the `digest` runs - it runs your function - Dont use a function inside your repeat, instead use `change` event on the input to detect if it's a number or not.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because angular **evals** the list when the **`times`** variable change and **$diggest** to build the **ng-reapeat** with the new value. You should use **$watch** instead:

```
angular.module('helloApp', [])
    .controller('helloController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.times = 1;
    $scope.$watch('times', function (newValue, oldVaue) {
        if (!angular.isNumber(newValue)) {
            $scope.times = oldVaue;
            alert('ENTER A VALID POSITIVE NUMBER PLEASE');
        }
    });

    $scope.getTimes = function (n) {
        if (angular.isNumber(n)) {
            return new Array(n);
        }
    };
}]);
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fals/75uv4ugb/

Answer (score 0):

By restructuring your logic and a slight change to your ng-repeat you can solve this issue:

[DEMO EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tas4n1b1/)

HTML:

```
<p ng-repeat="obj in array track by $index" ng-show="name.length">Welcome {{name}} !</p>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('helloApp', [])
    .controller('helloController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.array = [];

    $scope.populateArray = function (n, t) {
        $scope.array = [];
        if (t > 0) {
            for (i = 0; i < t; i++) {
                $scope.array.push(n);
            }
        }
    }

}]);
```

Comment: Furthermore, instead of doing your validation in the scope function you can use the form element to show/hide the error message for you: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms